# FileSystem that is has its root in a particular folder

Tags: java, filesystems

My application uses the file system and basically has a folder which it can read/write to - basically the root of the file system it can access.

In addition I need to mock out the file system for tests so need something to stick in my application context.

It would seem pretty obvious that Java's inbuilt `FileSystem` could be used here, but I've taken a look and it looks like an awful lot to implement for something simple like this which I would have expected to have already been done?

Is there anyway I can give a `Path` to a directory and get a `FileSystem` for which treats that directory as the root?

Comment: @azurefrog - that hooks into ZipFileSystemProvider I believe: `Constructs a new FileSystem to access the contents of a file as a file system`

Comment: Ah, you're right, I misread the docs.